# Transaction Deadlock

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssis, database-deadlocks

One of the report that I am working on fails at times with the below errors:

1. > Failed to create an IDataAdapter object. This provider may not be
   >   fully supported with the Execute SQL Task. Error message 'Transaction
   >   (Process ID 135) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process
   >   and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction
2. > Transaction (Process ID 123) was deadlocked on lock | communication
   >   buffer resources with another process and has been chosen as the
   >   deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.

This earlier used to happen very rarely but for the past couple of days the report has been failing frequently because of this reason.

Is there any way in which I can trace at what point exactly is this deadlock happening? The backend stored procedures have couple of temporary tables and one main table. This main table is accessed across the various stored procedures.

Could anyone please help me on this?

Comment: please elaborate more on the report. how are you generating the report? the Execute SQL Task is in SSIS. How does it relate to the report?

Comment: My report is a batch report. Hence the procedures are called through an ETL package

Comment: google "sql server profiler to trace deadlock" return something like https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/252/tracing-a-sql-server-deadlock/

Comment: Google for "how to catch deadlock"

Comment: If you're on 2012+, the deadlock information has [already been captured](http://blogs.technet.com/b/sqlpfeil/archive/2013/05/27/did-you-know-dead-locks-can-be-track-from-the-system-health-in-sql-2012.aspx)